# Error in data loader cliq

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I am using data loader from command line but I'm getting one error when I'm trying to verify if my password generated is correct or not

Command: `encrypt.bat -v generatedPassword secretKey`

Error:

> 2016-05-24 08:29:52,056 ERROR [main] security.EncryptionUtil main
>   (EncryptionUti l.java:336) - Error decrypting string:
>   10d05e725ebd1999668536e79f4335e6, error: Given final block not
>   properly padded

Also how I can schedule data load and export from command line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That error message is very misleading, but that is what is always displayed when the verification has failed, for whatever reason.

Looking at the command you ran, I believe the error is that you are missing the third parameter, the `Path to Key`

> `-v <encrypted> <decrypted value> [Path to Key]` Validate whether
>   decryption of encrypted value matches the decrypted value, optionally
>   provide key file

Ultimately, what you are looking for is a message that says:

> [main] security.EncryptionUtil main (EncryptionUtil.java:332) -
>   Decryption of encrypted value MATCHES the expected value